# Diagnostics for GEE in R

Tags: r, generalized-estimating-equations, diagnostic

I have been checking out which diagnostics to use for a GEE analysis. It seem that influence measures are appropriate (Preisser, 1996). Does anyone know of a package that can be used in R to examine influence measures in GEE? The "stats" package does not work: it returns an error when I run

```
influence.measures(model)
```

on a gee model, but works fine with an ordinary linear regression.

Comment: What package/function do you use to fit the GEE in `R`?

Comment: geepack see http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geepack/geepack.pdf