# Residual analysis and diagnostics for GEE Models in R

Tags: r, outliers, residuals, generalized-estimating-equations

Some colleagues asked me to perform a residual analysis on both linear models and generalized estimating equation (GEE) models. I know it is a faux-pas in some circles to remove outliers, but in our field it is common as a sensitivity analysis. In R, there are some great tools as diagnostics for linear models in the influence package using the `rstudent()` function.

I am wondering if there are any suggestions on how to perform a similar studentized residual test for GEE models? I am also wondering the validity of doing this, considering the residuals are not independent?

A previous poster asked a similar question and was directed to the `geeglm()` function in the geepack package. (That post is here: [Diagnostics for GEE in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63698/diagnostics-for-gee-in-r).)

When I use `geeglm()` on my GEE model and try to use any of the functions in the influence package like `rstudent()`, I get the following error:

```
> test.gee <- geeglm(fsiq ~peabody+depress, id=id, data=df_long, 
                     family="gaussian", corstr="exchangeable")
> rstudent(test.gee, type="pearson")
Error in match.arg(type) : 
'arg' should be one of “pearson”, “working”, “response”
```

Not sure if it's a coding error or error in my logic. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this question is on-topic for CV, but you should be aware that it is close to the border. Questions asking for code, for functions to do something, or why you are getting a particular error, are off-topic for CV (see our [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). *Some* questions of that type can be asked on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), but some will be off-topic there as well. Be aware that the answers you get here may help you understand the issues raised in your question but not eg explain the nature of the error or point out a handy function.